# How to make CIFilter's CIGlassDistortion texture's height match the image?

Tags: swift, mobile, textures, cifilter

Despite of using the same ciImage for texture and image, on the result the texture has smaller height. Is there anything I'm missing in this code?

```
    var filter: CIFilter?
    
    switch style {
    case "gaussian":
        filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        filter?.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    case "motion":
        filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMotionBlur")
        filter?.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    case "glass":
        filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGlassDistortion")
        filter?.setValue(radius * 100, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputTexture")
        filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: ciImage.extent.size.width, y: ciImage.extent.size.height), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
    default:
        return
    }
    
    filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    
    guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else { return }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some `CIFilter`s return images with greater `extent` than the input image, like `CIGaussianBlur` or `CIGlassDistortion`.

But you can crop the output back to the same `extent` as the input, so that they will match again:

```swift
guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage.cropped(to: ciInput.extent) else { return }
```